# @ Registration doesn't resolve controls for "DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, user-controls, dotnetnuke

Probably this something very simple, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.
I want to use `DNNTreeView` in `DNN 7.0.6` dev site. [This instruction page](http://rockpaperweb.com/blog/hierarchical-data-and-dnntreeview/) almost get me there. The `code behind` resolves the controls, but the `.ascx` doesn't and gives me the following warning

> Warning 102 Element ‘DnnTreeView’ is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing

the page looks like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="View.ascx.cs" Inherits="MySpace.Modules.MyModule.View" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web" %>


<dnn:DnnTreeView runat="server" ID="tvMain">
</dnn:DnnTreeView>
```

I'm using @ChrisHammond 's templates for the solution.
I have following dll references:

- DotNetNuke.dll
- DotNetNuke.Web.dll
- Telerik.Web.UI.dll

Can you smart guys find what I'm missing?

Comment: have you tried to do a build of the solution to see if that gets rid of the error?

Comment: Yes. compilation succeed, but it doesn't help. In the meanwhile tried [this](http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2010/07/21/95.aspx) and rebooting the station, without any progress

Comment: Are you getting a "warning" when building, or are you getting an error when loading on the page?

Comment: @ChrisHammond The warning is in the view.ascx for line: <dnn:DnnTreeView runat="server" ID="tvMain">. in the code behind Intellisense works, but not in the .ASCX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just a warning, I wouldn't worry about it, that is fairly common with DNN module development using the WAP approach. If it works in DNN, then just let it go :D

You might check to make sure that you don't have a virtual directory/application on the DESKTOPMODULES folder in IIS, or on the module's folder itself.

Comment: yeah, no virtual directory/application, that already took care, as you always recommend. You are the best! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've found a possible solution for the "not a known element" warning.  I was pulling my heart out looking for it, but I have one that works for me.  All you need to do is add a bin folder to your module and put these dll's in the bin folder: DotNetNuke.dll, DotNetNuke.Web.dll, DotNetNuke.WebControls.dll, Telerik.Web.UI.dll.  It doesn't matter if they are in the site bin folder, they need to be in the project bin folder, too.

I have a full explanation [here](http://rockpaperweb.com/blog/the-dreaded-not-a-known-element-error/)

Comment: It've worked for me, I hope it is permanent. You've saved countless lives!